# How do you increment multiple fields in one query in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do you increment multiple fields in one query in [mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose)?

For example, here is the working mongo query that I want to use with a mongoose model.

```
db.users.update({ userId:89 }, { $inc : { "subjectResults.attempts" : 1, "subjectResults.total_time" : 10, "subjectResults.total_score" : 100 } })
```

The above query is working in plain vanilla Mongo.

Edit: I have removed the confusing property name that lead to the comments below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The APIs are nearly identical. Instead of `db.users.update` in straight mongodb, it's `UserModel.update` in mongoose. Pass in the exact same query and update options object.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there might be a more elegant way to do it when dealing with model instances but that makes sense.